# Azure AD B2C: Where can I find phone number from MFA on access token?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to retrieve the telephonenummer from the decoded accesstoken in c#:

```
return dec.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "emails").Value;
```

This does return me the user email adresse. But I cannot retrieve phone number like this.

It is typed for MFA, it is not a claim as I cannot even registre telephone:

[image]

Where would I find the user telephone number?

Answer (score 0):

All the user attributes in B2C are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes).

The closest seems to be "telephoneNumber".

But note it can only be used in a custom policy.

Comment: what do u mean by "custom policy" ? because I set up my own policy, wouldnt know how to make it any other way (B2C_newUser) flow

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview